# Installed TeX Live 2022, but texi2pdf still links to TeX Live 2017/Debian

Tags: texinfo

I have installed texlive 2022

But doing

`texi2pdf /home/Opstk/bin/devguide/fredholm.tex`

gives

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
```

Comment: Exactly how did you add tl22 to your path?

Comment: With `texlive="/home/Opstk/texlive/2022"`, `PATH=${texlive}/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`, and `export PATH`

Comment: In which file, and how is the texlive variable related to the path variable. Details matter here.

Comment: Plus that texlive variable does not point to the relevant bin part of the texlive path

Comment: In my `.bashrc`. `texlive` is the basepath for texlive 2022.  Thus the actual path is `PATH=/home/Opstk/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`.

Comment: That seems OK, but remember that any editors you start from a menu or similar will never use bash, so will never see this change. It's a good idea to add it to `.profile` as well (you'll need to relogin for it to work).

Comment: Is texi2pdf even shipped with texlive anymore?

Comment: texi2pdf is not a texlive program. you must be picking up an old one use `pdflatex`

Comment: After doing as instructed `pdflatex fredholm.tex`, I still get `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./fredholm.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo)) (./gungadin.sty
(./expkv/expkv-opt.sty`

Comment: What's the output of `which -a pdflatex` and `alias pdflatex`? Are the changes to your path working? What does `echo $PATH` show?

Comment: `which -a pdflatex` gives `/usr/bin/pdflatex`.  Whilst `alias pdflatex` does not find anything.  Have added the Tex Live installation path to `PATH`.  Found out that I was not sourcing my `.bashrc`, which exported the path.  Have now added the path to `.bash_profile`.